# How to show types in js files VSCode like ts files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some files

- Compenent.js
- index.js
- types.js

How i can avoid `Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.` error, and show types in js files?

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: js doesn't have types beyond those given by the typeof function (string,number, object,etc), typescript was developed to redress this lack so typescript types have no value in js hence why you are seeing the error they literally can't be used